# "Variable was not declared in this scope" in C and C++

Tags: c++, c, compilation

I find a difference between C and C++ today.
I separated the program in two different files, this is my C test:

```
/* in file main.c*/
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 3, b = 4;
    int c = sum(a, b);
    printf("%d\n", c);
}
```

and

```
/* In file sum.c */
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

then, I compiled them `gcc main.c sum.c`， no errors and the result is correct. Following is my C++ test, I also separated them in two different files:

```
/* in file main.cpp*/
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 3, b = 4;
    int c = sum(a, b);
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

and

```
/* In file sum.cpp */
#include <iostream>

int sum(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Compile them `g++ main.cpp sum.cpp`. An error occurs: `error: ‘sum’ was not declared in this scope`. If I put a declaration `int sum(int, int)` in the file `main.cpp`, then no error occurs. Why there is such a different between C and C++? What's the best way to solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a feature C++ introduced: don't assume you know a function signature unless you've actually seen a declaration or definition.  Makes it easier to report improper function usage earlier in the compiler & link process, and with C++ name mangling the exact types of arguments are needed to know which symbol the code will need to be linked against - the type determination is based on matching against candidates, with a variety of standard conversions / implicit constructions / implicit casts possible.

The proper way to solve this is by creating a `sum.h` header file:

```
#ifndef SUM_H
#define SUM_H
int sum(int, int);
#endif
```

This should be included on the first line or `sum.cpp` (so you'll get an error if `sum.h` content evolves to depend on `<iostream>` content but forgets to include it itself), and in `main.cpp` before or after the other include as you like (I'd hazard most people would put after, but that's a stylistic choice).

Comment: C99 regrettably follows C++98 and permits you to omit the `return 0;` at the end of `main()`.  I still prefer to see it written explicitly, and write it explicitly myself, but …

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: oh - think that's after the last time I used C in anger ;-) - no regrets.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I know creating a header file will solve the problem, it's necessary especially for big programs.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: C99 also enforces that a function must be declared before calling it

Comment: @MattMcNabb: hmmm... makes me wonder if gcc defaults to enabling C99... sure OP can google that.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I have just tried, with a **-Wall** option and no **-std=c99**, you can see warnings, not an error. So it is not recommended in c89, either.

Comment: @panqihg the compiler is being helpful but doesn't have to warn  (and the code is legal in C89)

Answer (score 0):

Of course creation of h-file is the best option. But as a minimum you can include `sum` function declaration before `main`, e.g.:

```cpp
/* in file main.c*/
#include <stdio.h>

// external function declaration (instead of h-file)
int sum(int, int);

int main()
{
    int a = 3, b = 4;
    int c = sum(a, b);
    printf("%d\n", c);
    return 0;
}
```